# google subscriptions how to test?

Tags: sandbox, checkout, subscription, recurring

I've inherited a project that uses google subscriptions and generates orders that recur on a monthly basis.

I have set-up a sandbox buyer account, but I'm unsure how to test the recurring order system, without having to wait a month in between.

Ideally I'd be able to re-bill a monthly recurring order after a few minutes, whilst in sandbox mode.

It'd also be useful to send callback xml to the callback script to verify that all is working in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try setting the `period` string to `DAILY` for the duration of testing. This will charge the user every day rather than every month, so you will not have to wait as long. Once your finished testing that the charges work daily, change it back to `MONTHLY`.

```
<subscription type="merchant" period="DAILY" type="merchant">
```

For more information, see the `subscription` in the `XML Tag Definitions` section of [this site](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions).

Hope this helps!